# Typescript Angular NgModelController - get raw wtring

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have something like this

```
<form>
<my-directive ...>
<input name="foo" ng-model="vm.foo" />
<form>
```

I would like to get the value of ng-model's string value inside my directive i.e. 'vm.foo'

My directive takes in the form controller (ng.IForController) and does this

```
angular.forEach(this.form, (value, key) => {
            if (typeof value === 'object' && value.hasOwnProperty('$modelValue')) {
                var element = angular.element(value); // this is of type NgModelController
                // HOW DO I RETRIEVE element[ng-model] as a string?
        });
```

The 'element' variable gets a value of type NgModelController. From this, how can i get the raw value of the string ng-model is bound to? The return value i expect is 'vm.foo' ?

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish? Would need to write a small test to see if it's possible at all (I'm pretty sure it is). However, I'm not sure you are headed in the right direction.

Comment: I think, but I can't recall for sure, that the transformation happens before the controller is bound to the isolate scope object and you will need to access this value via the link function which has the form `(scope, element, attributes, controllers)`.

Comment: I'm preparing a brief, just need to articulate it properly. For now is it not possible from NgModelController to be able to get the raw string?